# TextView Begins to shrink the content view once rotated past a certain point

Tags: ios, textview, rotation, autolayout

As you can see in the video below, the text begins to clip to an increasingly shrinking rect as the textView rotates beyond a certain point.  How can I get the text to remain in place throughout the rotation?

Here is my rotation Code.  I have tried rotating the view's transform as well as the layer's transform.

```
func rotate(radians: CGFloat) {
    netRotation += radians // property that tracks rotation over time for other purposes
    layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(layer.transform, radians, 0, 0, 1)
}
```

Here are the properties I set on the textView

```
textComponent.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.centerXAnchor)
textComponent.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superView.centerYAnchor)
textComponent.isScrollEnabled = false
textComponent.translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = false
clipsToBounds = false
```

[image]

Comment: You've left out a lot of the code that could be (likely is) affecting your text view. Using this quick example, with a slider to control the rotation, there is no "shrinkage" - https://pastebin.com/guf13v60

Comment: I've isolated the problem to rotation on my own.  When I disable the scale/translation changes it behaves in the same way